# How to list all files and directories in current directory, whose Second character is a digit

Tags: linux, command-line, files, directory, command

What command is used to list all files and directories in the current directory, where the **second character of its name is a digit**.

Can we use `grep` here?

Comment: Something like `ls -d ?[0-9]*`?

Comment: You need to differentiate between file name and file contents, here. `ls` e.g. is working on file names, `grep` on contents.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli can u explain  all the content?

Comment: As @RudiC asked from you: Do you mean the file whose **name** is to contain the digit, or whose **content** is to contain to digit? My comment, assumed that you are asking file **names**.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli I have some files like a2b, c2,d6,ef3.... We need to show all the files except ef3 because there is no Digit in second character

Answer (score 4):

If you want to list all files whose second character is a digit, you can use [Bash wildcards](http://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm) like this: `?[0-9]*`

where:

- `?` represents any single character,
- `[0-9]` represents any single character in the range `0`..`9`, and finally
- `*` represents any number of characters.

To list such files on the terminal you can use `echo`, `ls`, or any other command that will output its parameters. For example:

- `ls -d ?[0-9]*`
- `echo ?[0-9]*`

In the first case (`ls`), we need to add the `-d` parameter to list directories themselves, not their contents, in case that the file name we "match" is actually a directory.